# Allocated memory size by pointer in RPGLE

Tags: pointers, memory-management, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Is there a way to retrive the allocated memory size by a pointer in RPGLE?
Memory is allocated with `%ALLOC()` bif.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way even with MI builtins. Is there a need for it? What _business_ problem do you need to solve?

Comment: Hi! Inside the main program I'm populating an array, defined as BASED on a pointer. I'm doing so to avoid a maximum dimension, as I don't know how many elements there will be.
The main program is then called by another program, passing the pointer to the array as input (so the main one can use it to allocate memory).
So, I'd like to avoid passing another parameter (output) to identity the number of elements inserted, as I have the size in byte of an element of the array.

Comment: Note that even system APIs require lenghts/sizes when you pass a pointer to them. If they can't do it, it's unlikely user programs can. What problem is there in passing one more parm?

Comment: I'm trying to simplify as much as I can. You know, some people never worked with dynamic memory, especially older programmers. And I got reprehended because I use "strange" (yeah...) techniques. But it's ok, I'll keep the parameter.

Comment: Ah. Understood (though my career has fortunately mostly been the opposite with encouragement to push ahead and drag others along). The "system APIs" point can fit if necessary to defend the... ummm... 'complexity'.

Comment: Luckily I'm at the beginning of my career. I think this kind of problems comes with big companies that have a lot of employees and want maximum maintainability.

Comment: Don't give up. I started 40+ yrs ago at a multi-billion$, multi-national, DJ40 company. Last job was for perhaps largest software co. in the IBM i space, and before that as sys pgmr at the world's largest PC manufacturing plant. A few jobs at some of the smallest  in between plus a couple local&state govt. staff positions. Progress is always possible, but maint. is indeed important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take the following approach. Build a dynamic array service program that contains the necessary sub-procedures to process a dynamic array. Functions like:

- CreateArray() - creates a dynamic array and returns a handle to it (could be a pointer)
- ArrayPush(handle: element) - adds an element to the end of the array
- ArrayPop(handle) - removes and returns the last element in the array
- ArraySize(handle) - returns the current number of elements in the array
- etc.

The caller would know the size of the elements, but you can use `varchar` and `options(*varying)` to allow the sub-procedure to determine the length of the element being loaded, or if you would be loading data structures, you could use `opdesc`. Specifying `opdesc' is entirely transparent to the caller, it would be specified in the prototype, so the caller doesn't even have to know about it. The sub-procedure can then use a system API to interrogate the operational descriptor. I believe it is a CEE API, you can look that up. To hold the array, you can use a user space. The nice thing about them is you don't have to reallocate when you space is full, it expands automatically up to 16Mb.

Or you could use a pointerr to the user space to back the based array. Ted Holt has examples of doing what you are looking for here. http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg051006-story02.html

Here is my sub-procedure to create an auto-extending user space and return a pointer to it.

```
   // Standard Error Code Format
   dcl-ds ErrorCdType1_t   Qualified Template Inz;
     BytesProv             Int(10)   Inz(%size(ErrorCdType1_t));
     BytesAvail            Int(10);
     MsgId                 Char(7);
     Data                  Char(1024) Pos(17);
   end-ds;

   // Qualified Name
   dcl-s Name_t            Char(10) Template Inz('');
   dcl-ds QualName_t       Qualified Template Inz;
     Name                  Like(Name_t) Inz('');
     Lib                   Like(Name_t) Inz('*LIBL');
   end-ds;

   // =====================================================================
   // User Space APIs
   // =====================================================================

   // Create User Space
   dcl-pr CreateUs;
     UserSpace             LikeDs(QualName_t) Const;
     Description           Char(50) Const;
     ReturnPtr             Pointer;
     ErrorCd               LikeDs(ErrorCdType1_t)
                           Options(*NoPass);
   end-pr;
   dcl-pr quscrtus     ExtPgm('QUSCRTUS');
     UserSpace             LikeDs(QualName_t) Const;
     ExtAttribute          Char(10)  Const;
     InitialSize           Int(10)   Const;
     InitialValue          Char(1)   Const;
     PublicAuthority       Char(10)  Const;
     TextDescription       Char(50)  Const;
     Replace               Char(10)  Const  Options(*NoPass);
     ErrorCd               LikeDs(ErrorCdType1_t)
                           Options(*NoPass);
     Domain                Char(10)  Const  Options(*NoPass);
     XferSizeReq           Int(10)   Const  Options(*NoPass);
     OptimumSpaceAlign     Char(1)   Const  Options(*NoPass);
   end-pr;

   // Return Pointer to User Space
   dcl-pr qusptrus     ExtPgm('QUSPTRUS');
     UserSpace             LikeDs(QualName_t) Const;
     ReturnPtr             Pointer;
     ErrorCd               LikeDs(ErrorCdType1_t)
                           Options(*NoPass);
   end-pr;

   // Change User Space Attributes
   dcl-pr quscusat     ExtPgm('QUSCUSAT');
     ReturnedLib           Char(10);
     UserSpace             LikeDs(QualName_t) Const;
     Attribs               LikeDs(us_Attributes_t) Const;
     Error                 LikeDs(ErrorCdType1_t);
   end-pr;

   // ----- Data Structures -------
   dcl-ds us_VariableLengthRec_t   Qualified Template Inz;
     key              Int(10) Inz(0);
     datalen          Int(10) Inz(0);
     data             Int(10);
     charData         Char(1) Overlay(data);
   end-ds;

   dcl-ds us_Attributes_t   Qualified Template Inz;
     numRec           Int(10) Inz(0);
     vlRecs           LikeDs(us_VariableLengthRec_t) Dim(5)
                      Inz(*LikeDs);
   end-ds;

   // ----- Constants -------------
   // Variable Length Record Key
   dcl-c USATR_AUTO_EXTEND       3;   // data Char(1) *On or *Off

   // -----------------------------
   // Create an automatically extendable user space
   // -----------------------------
   dcl-proc CreateUs Export;
     dcl-pi *n;
       UserSpace             LikeDs(QualName_t) Const;
       Description           Char(50) Const;
       ReturnPtr             Pointer;
       ErrorCd               LikeDs(ErrorCdType1_t)
                             Options(*NoPass);
     end-pi;

     dcl-ds ercd      LikeDs(ErrorCdType1_t)  Inz(*LikeDs);
     dcl-ds usatr     LikeDs(us_Attributes_t) Inz(*LikeDs);
     dcl-ds MsgFile   LikeDs(QualName_t)      Inz(*LikeDs);

     dcl-s Lib        Char(10) Inz('');

     if %parms() >= %parmnum(ErrorCd);
       ercd = ErrorCd;
     endif;

     // Create User Space
     quscrtus(UserSpace: '': 8192: x'00': '*EXCLUDE': Description:
              '*NO': ercd);
     if ercd.msgid <> '';
       exsr CheckErcd;
       return;
     endif;

     // Retrieve a pointer to the space
     qusptrus(UserSpace: ReturnPtr: ercd);
     if ercd.msgid <> '';
       exsr CheckErcd;
       return;
     endif;

     // Make Space automatically extendable
     usatr.numrec = 1;
     usatr.vlrecs(1).key = USATR_AUTO_EXTEND;
     usatr.vlrecs(1).datalen = 1;
     usatr.vlrecs(1).chardata = *On;
     quscusat(Lib: UserSpace: usatr: ercd);
     if ercd.msgid <> '';
       exsr CheckErcd;
       return;
     endif;

     // ===========================
     begsr CheckErcd;
       if %parms() >= %parmnum(ErrorCd);
         ErrorCd = ercd;
         return;
       else;
         // Send an escape message if you want to here
       endif;
     endsr;
   end-proc;
```

I did not include the code to send the escape message on error here, but you should be able to fill in those blanks. It is simply be a call to QMHSNDPM.

You call CreateUS something like this.

```
dcl-s pHandle       Pointer Inz(*null);
dcl-ds ercd         LikeDs(ErrorCdType1_t) Inz(*LikeDs);
CreateUS('TMPARRAY  QTEMP': 'Temporary Dynamic Array':
    pHandle: errcd);
```

You can use the user space like this:

```
dcl-ds dynArray     Qualified Dim(32767) Based(pArray);
  dsField1          Char(10);
  dsField2          Char(10);
  ...
end-ds;
dcl-s pArray        Pointer Inz(*null);

// Create the user space
pArray = pHandle;
```

Now you can add elements to your hearts content up to 32767 elements. You can define the dimensions of the array as larger if you want. Using this technique, your array isn't really dynamic, it actually has 32767 elements. But the storage isn't on your program heap, it is in a permanent user space object in QTEMP. To make it truly dynamic you would have to write the service program described above. It's not a huge task, but it isn't trivial either. Maybe this is an open source project waiting to happen.

Comment: Hi! I've never done something like that. Can we do a Java comparison?
It's something like ArrayDeque/ArrayList.
Each function will have a different prototype right?

Comment: @LppEdd CEEDOD could work because array element size is fixed. Good choice possibly. The pointer wouldn't be passed, though. The declared array would need to be passed, and the most useful declaration isn't clear. OpDescs are available on input parms, so caller needs to make declaration of options(*varsize) parm. And I haven't seen it work for a DIM() parm (but no thorough tests). Any example code for %alloc() memory, jmarkmurphy? User space pointer could also work, but not as simple as just passing element count parm.

Comment: @LppEdd And for user space, be sure to set the auto-extend attribute with Change User Space Attributes (QUSCUSAT) API if you need auto-extend.

Comment: I think the best and simplest approach, to avoid overcomplicating things is to use ALLOC and REALLOC. But I will give the userspace a shot! I like the idea

Comment: @LppEdd If you use the service program, you would have to write the sub-procedures yourself. It seems to me that someone has already done it, but I can't find it anywhere. If I were building it myself, I would not use ALLOC and REALLOC. I find it more complicated than using a user space since the user space can be configured to automatically extend. I will add my sub-procedure to create an auto-extend user space and return a pointer to it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the code! It will be useful also for others.
As I'm here, may I ask you why you initialize template DS?

Comment: One of the advantages of `Template` over just using `Based` with a dummy pointer is that you can set initial values for a template. Then when I create a data structure from the template I can use `Inz(*LikeDS)` to initialize the DS like the template. Usually the initial values are just defaults, but not always. I tend to initialize my variables simply because most intermittent bugs are initialization errors.